# Load cog for multiple bots

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Using `discord.py`, I can run multiple bots from one piece of code, but I'm looking for a way to load a cog or extension into multiple bots. For a test case, I have `bot.py`, which handles loading the cog and starting the bot, and `cog.py` which is a simple cog that incrementally adds 1 to a counter

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')

client1.load_extension('cog')
client2.load_extension('cog')

@client1.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client1 ready')

@client1.command()
async def ping():
    await client1.say('Pong')

@client2.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client2 ready')

@client2.command()
async def ping():
    await client2.say('Pong')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client1.start('TOKEN1'))
loop.create_task(client2.start('TOKEN2'))
loop.run_forever()
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog:

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def add(self):
        self.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % self.counter)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Using `!ping` will make `client1` respond with Pong, while using `~ping` will make `client2` respond with Pong, which is expected behaviour.

However, only one of the bots will respond to both `!add` and `~add`, with the counter increasing with either command. This seems dependent on which bot loads the cog last.

Is there a way to have the correct bot respond to the correct command while also having the counter increase with either command? I know I can split it into two cogs and save the result to a file for example, but is it possible to do it without saving the counter to disk?

Comment: `on_ready` does some stuff that you'll have to do manually.  You might find [this github issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/516) helpful

Comment: I've edited my question to load the cogs outside the ready events. Note how `client2` loads the cog second, meaning `client2` is the bot that will respond to !add and ~add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `@commands.command()` is only loaded once. Therefore, both of the bots shared the same `Command` instance. What you need is to add the command on an instance level, and not by the `@commands.command()` decorator.

```
class TestCog:
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.add_command(commands.Command('add', self.add))

    async def add(self):
        TestCog.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % TestCog.counter)
```

or:

```
class TestCog:
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.command()(self.add)

    async def add(self):
        TestCog.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % TestCog.counter)
```

In order to make both bots share the same attribute. You want class attribute, not instance's.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes the correct bot respond to their respective commands, but the counters are independent. Is their a way to have a single counter that increases when either command is called without saving to disk?

Comment: @Benjin my bad, I didn't read that part of the question. Edited.