# How to run multiple discord bots with one Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to create a script that runs multiple discord bots at the same time. So far I have achieved how to run a single account but I have hit a brick wall in my attempts to repeat the process multiple times with different accounts within the same `python discord.py` script.

```
import discord

Email = [];
Pass = [];


client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Connection Made Succesfully")
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('email', 'password')
```

Comment: It appears that you are using actual accounts to log in. If this is true, I recommend that you use bot accounts and tokens instead of logging in with an actual account because self-bots violate the discord ToS.

Comment: You have to handle the event loop yourself.  See what @Benjin is doing in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302170/load-cog-for-multiple-bots